# Error deploying appxbundle into hololens from device portal

Tags: .net, deployment, uwp, hololens

In the past we sucessfully deploy  our apps into hololens through the device portal but we are now finding an annoying issue; we have this error message:

> Installation Failed Failure reason: Windows cannot install package
>   HololensLayar_1.0.5.0_x86__pzq3xp76mxafg because this package depends
>   on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework
>   "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1" published by "CN=Microsoft
>   Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US",
>   with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version
>   1.1.27004.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1" currently installed are:
>   {Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25915.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe} Failure
>   text: Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
>   (0x80073cf3)

.... which seems to be a dependecy error. We had issues like this in the past and it was usually fixed by adding the required "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1" package  during the installation as framework package. However this is not working anymore and we are having the same error.

We tried to update our Visual Studio and Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 to the most recent version [image], 1.1.27004.0, which seems to be the very same one requested by the error, but it doesn't make any difference... the device portal keep insisting with the same error.

Can anyone provide some advice, please?

Comment: hello, we are having the same issue on Hololens device since an update of Visual Studio start of the week.

Comment: Couln't find a solution for this. The only thing that worked was to change the scripting backend in Unity->other settings from .net to il2cpp. This prevent dependencies and so there is no error when deploying. 

As it seems that Unity support for UWP->.net is deprecated  I guess this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Unity 3D is stopping the .net support for UWP platforms so I guess the best thing to do even if this is a VS bug to be fixed soon it's better to move from .net to il2cpp backend as soon as possible.

[image: Screenshot from Unity 2018.3.0f2]

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Microsoft Support and this is a known bug from a recent visual studio update. The only possible thing is to wait an update or do one of the possible workaround that include passing to IL2CPP.

https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3346